# Is it possible to make slide Menus in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am stuck trying to make the following kind of slide menu in Swing.
[image]

I have searched entire web but I didn't find any tutorial or maybe I missed that. Can you please suggest a solution or a tutorial? I don't need code but just the components to use.

Comment: What do you mean by slider?

Comment: The image shows that.When we click on the middle dots it comes from the right.

Comment: The image shows a lot of things. I suppose a JSplitPane could be used. Dunno how well the sliding will work.

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple in Swing.

What you are looking for is a `JSplitPane`.  You can start with it closed and it has arrows (or other symbols depending on your look and feel) that can be clicked on.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html

Note: A slider is a very different component.  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

**Edit**: Based on your comment it sounds like actually are looking for an animated opening of the slider (which is hard to tell from a static image).

In that case this question is a duplicate, look here: [Animation for divider movement in JSplitPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255646/animation-for-divider-movement-in-jsplitpane)

Comment: I have used that.It comes at once and goes away within a blink.Not smooth.