# JSplitPane hide and show the right section

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a JSplitPane with two sections. I want to hide the right section when I click a button, and bring it back when I click on that same button again.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (PrincipalSplitPane.getDividerSize() == 1.0)
        PrincipalSplitPane.setDividerLocation(0.0);
    else
        PrincipalSplitPane.setDividerLocation(1.0);
    }
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of `getDividerSize() == 1.0` as a predicate; `setDividerLocation()` seems to work in this [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5071109/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getRightComponent()` method of the `JSplitPane` and then call the `setVisible(false)` to hide it.

To show it again, call the `setVisible(true)` and set the **divider location** using the `setDividerLocation(...)` method.

### An Example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ResizingSplitPane extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JButton clickMe;
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;
    private JSplitPane split;

    // private int dividerLocation;

    public ResizingSplitPane()
    {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Center Panel
        clickMe = new JButton("Click Me!!");
        clickMe.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(clickMe);

        // Bottom Panel
        leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        rightPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        leftPanel.add(new JLabel("Left"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        rightPanel.add(new JLabel("Right"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, leftPanel, rightPanel);
        split.setResizeWeight(.5d);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(split, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ResizingSplitPane();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource() == clickMe)
        {
            if (split.getRightComponent().isVisible())
            {
                // dividerLocation = split.getDividerLocation();
                split.getRightComponent().setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {
                split.getRightComponent().setVisible(true);
                split.setDividerLocation(0.5);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you need to save the previous `divider` location, you can store the current location into a variable (like the `dividerLocation` variable in the code) and then when calling the `setDividerLocation` pass in that variable.