# JSplitPane Setting Resize Weight not Working

Tags: java, swing, java-8, swingx

I am trying to set the weight of the `splitter` to `0.9` yet it does not seem to work. What am I missing and what am i to do? I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625762/setting-divider-location-on-a-jsplitpane-doesnt-work) post, yet I could not neither understand nor solve the problem of mine. What I want basically is 
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dmF4.png) though the split pane and the table is always %50,%50. So `splitter.setResizeWeight( 0.9 );` is not working. 
Here's the code of the panel:

```
 public FlightPanel( final SomeOtherClass category, final SomeClass dar2 )
 {
   this.detailsPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 0, 1 ) );
      this.sum = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 0, 1 ) );
      this.model =
            new FlightPanelTableModel(...);
  this.timeTable = new JTable( this.model );
  this.timeTable.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
  this.setLayout( new GridLayout( 0, 1 ) );


  this.treeView = new FlightPanelTreeView( dar2 );
  ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent( this.treeView );

  this.detailsPanel.add( this.treeView );
  final JSplitPane splitter =
        new JSplitPane( JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, new JScrollPane( this.timeTable ),
              new JScrollPane( this.detailsPanel ) );
  splitter.setResizeWeight( 0.9 );

  this.sum.add( splitter );
  this.add( this.sum );
 }
```

How could I solve it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213542/how-to-set-divider-location-for-jsplitpane-on-start-up) can help you?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Yey, it helped me. But I am not very sure if I am implementing it in the right way. Thank you.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Working just fine, Thank you so much sir.